# Indexing json data from Android app to SOLR

Tags: android, json, solr, lucene

I'm new to SOLR, below is my question,

In my schema.xml file, one field's type is text. like below

```
 <field name="myData" type="text" indexed="false"  stored="true"  />
```

And the field type text is defined as below:

> ```
> <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
>   <analyzer type="index">
>     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
>     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
>   </analyzer>
>   <analyzer type="query">
>     <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
>     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
>   </analyzer>
> ```

When I'm trying to post some dummy data through Postman, below error is coming:

> {"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":1},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","java.lang.NumberFormatException"],"msg":"ERROR:
>   [doc=0_911531150004234224_2017-09-27 13:05:07] Error adding field
>   'violationData'='Was not moving' msg=For input string: \"Was not
>   moving\"","code":400}}

Data which I'm trying to post:

```
 {
     "myData" : "Was not moving"
  }
```

I think my format of data is not correct. Please Help!

What data should be sent for `solr.TextField` type.

Comment: Are you building your JSON manually? Have you reloaded the schema after changing it? Has it been a number before? Do you have the `_version_` field defined? How about an `id` field? Since you have a different field name in your error message than what you have in your schema .. that seems weird as well..

Comment: Yes everything is actually working corectly, even for "myData" if I'm sending empty quotes, It is accepting the data. "myData" : ""